# permission denied on database and file on web server

Tags: laravel, apache

> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
>   file_put_contents(/var/www/html/moha/storage/framework/sessions/rGlwXEnWZF6hnlZY9URsoioiFSjnDsHZyzpbJLiV):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: Hint: chmod path `/var/www/html/moha/storage/framework/sessions/` chmod level 600 should work to allow PHP user to make files.

Comment: I tried this too.. it didnt even work for 777

Comment: what does `ls -l` within the path `/var/www/html/moha/storage/framework/` print.. Also use PHP functions like `getmyuid() ` and `getmygid()` and `get_current_user()` to get information about PHP's user.. i have a feeling you also need to change the folder group to the php's user group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This command allows you edit your file in without root permission.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/moha/storage/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver (Apache, Nginx or other) should be able to write on the storage directory. Consider that `www-data` is the webserver user (default), at root of your project, run the following commands:

`sudo chown -R www-data. storage/`

`sudo chmod -R 777 storage/`